# php class or regex to check regex pattern itself (at least checking the delimiters/syntax..)

Tags: php, regex, class, automation

I wrote a valitor class with a fair amount of regex in there.
Using Eclipse Regex Util, it is able to report regex pattern "mistakes", so I'm wondering whether I could find a regex - or a php subclass - , to check that the regex pattern I'm calling is a correct regex pattern, nesting a dedicated  in-class method, on top of checking/testing them unitary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just try using `preg_match()` with the regex on an empty string; if it returns `False`, an error has occurred, meaning that the pattern is invalid.

Comment: thx, that matches the simple smart idea I was looking for, even if I was dreaming of some existing tools in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim correctly suggests, the best way to *validate* a PCRE syntax regex is to try and compile it (by running it through `preg_match()`). His should be selected as the best answer (I've already given it my +1).

However, if anyone is interested in seeing how one can decompose a PCRE syntax regex to check for proper matching of (possibly nested) parentheses groups, I've written a JavaScript utility which does precisely this. The purpose of the script is pretty useful, too: It allows a web page to display a regex such that a user can mouse over any bracket to highlight and see its matching bracket. It identifies numbered capturing groups with a tooltip and highlights any erroneous orphaned unmatched parentheses in red.

### Dynamic (?:Regex Highlighting)++ with Javascript!

Here is the documentation page which describes the regular expressions used by the script:
[DynamicRegexHighlighter](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighter.html)

And here is the tester page where you can apply dynamic highlighting to any regex:
[DynamicRegexHighlighterTester](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighterTester.html)

If you are into regex, I think that you will agree that this is a pretty cool tool. The tester page is very handy for reading long, complex regexes that are not written in commented, free-spacing mode.

This is released under the MIT license and the project is hosted over on GitHub.

Comment: Thx, and congratulation, that's an impressive tool !! The translation of the engine into PHP would be great for me as the purpose is to debug/control/manage myriad of php regexes on the server side, "on the fly" (hummm... server side).